# How to find out an extension's content type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, content-type, paperclip

Where could I find out the content type for a specific file format/extension?
For example, I know that an mp3 can be one of the following content types:

```
'application/mp3', 'application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3'
```

What would be the content type for a zip file? Where would I find out that information for other content types?

I need this for purposes of validation with ruby on rail's paperclip plugin.

Thanks!

---

**Update: I just found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp) and thought it may be useful to other people**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that an mp3 can be one of the following content types

Only `audio/mpeg` is valid. The rest are bogus and won't generally work anywhere.

> What would be the content type for a zip file?

`application/zip`.

> Where would I find out that information for other content types?

The proper list of all registered media types is [at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/). Of course, there are many more types that have not been registered, largely those with the `x` prefix.

If you want to find out on the fly what your machine thinks a particular extension is using a server-side script, you can find that in an OS-specific place. On Windows, the file extension/type information is stored in the Registry. On desktop Linux, it's in `/usr/share/mime`. On an Apache web server, you might want to re-use Apache's `mime.types` table.

> for a specific file format/extension?

File extensions are unstandardised, and not a reliable way of checking the type of a resource on the web, including a file upload. File-extension-to-media-type mappings are an OS/installation-specific issue so you can't know what media type a file is from extension on another machine. Furthermore, some operating systems don't even use file extensions to determine type (or only use them as a fallback).

Even looking at the `Content-Type` supplied with a file upload is of little use, since it's so often wrong due to bad setup at the client side. I guess this is why the bogus types like `application/mp3` have crept into the list above, because some time one browser somewhere on a badly-set-up machine sent the wrong type. But browsers can always send any old wrong type... you're just as likely to get a `text/plain` MP3.

If you need to allow the user to set a definitive content-type for the uploaded resource, you'll have to let them manually pick it. Of course you can use a bit of script hacking to make useful guesses like “if it ends with .jpeg, it's *probably* a JPEG” and make that selection automatically. But in the general case it is not reliable to guess type from user-submitted file extension.